# Modify actual element value in array numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, access-modifiers

I can't modify the actual value of a numpy array in a loop.
My code is the following :

```
labels_class = np.copy(labels_train)
for label in labels_class:
  labels_class[label] = 1 if (label == classifier) else 0
```

`labels_class` - is just a numpy array of size N and of values [0, 39].
The value of `labels_class[label]` is correct(==modified) in the loop, but outside of the loop `labels_class`remains unchanged.

I have also tried `nditer`, did not work :

```
 for label in np.nditer(labels_class, op_flags=['readwrite']):
      label = 1 if (label == classifier) else 0
```

In the [reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values), it is said that **"to actually modify the element of the array, x should be indexed with the ellipsis"**

**How do I do that? What is the syntax?**

Comment: Perhaps you meant to [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) through the numpy array. Simply iterating over an iterable yields the elements of the iterable, not the indexes of the elements.

Comment: I meant accessing the elements of the array in the loop and _modifying_ _actual_ values of it.

Comment: To actually change `label` you have to use something like `label[:]=...` or `label[...] = ...`.   Review the `nditer` tutorial if you want to go that route.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values  'modifying array values with nditer'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your iterator is not creating indices, but the actual elements in the array

```
for label in labels_class
```

In the above `label` is not an index, but the actual element you are trying to change

You can do something like this:

```
for i, label in enumerate(labels_class):
     labels_class[i] = 1 if (label == classifier) else 0
```

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you. However, I must say that in `for label in labels_class`  `label` is not the _actual_ element but a copy.

Comment: You don't need the `1 if ... else 0` part, you can just leave `label == classifier`.

Comment: @Oleksandra, python variables are different than c variables, for example. Python `ints` and `floats` are immutable so there is no difference between a copy and the _actual element_.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for modifying array values with `nditer` is demonstrated at

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
for x in np.nditer(a, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    x[...] = 2 * x
```

'x should be indexed with the ellipsis' refers to the `x[...]`.

Indexing with `enumerate` is perfectly fine as well.  But this is the way to do it with `nditer`.  See later sections in the `nditer` page about using `flags=['f_index']`.

When iterating over arrays you need to clearly understand the difference between variables which are indexes, scalars, or array elements which can be modified.  `x = 1` is not the same as `A[i]= 1` or `x[...]=1`.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
labels_class[label_class == classifier] = 1
labels_class[label_class != classifier] = 0
```